# How to get the verified publisher of a signed program?

Tags: c#, windows, code-signing

In C#, how do I get the verified publisher of a signed .exe file? I am working on a program blocking application, and would like to be able to detect the publisher, if any, of a program.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

> X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile()

If you pass name of the .exe or .msi or any signed file to this method, it will create a `X509Certificate` object. You can then use GetName() method to get certification publisher information. Below code should get you started if you have not discovered it already.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ConsoleApplication1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Certificate xcert = null;
            try
            {
                 xcert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(args[0]);
                 Console.WriteLine(args[0] + "\t" + xcert.GetName() + "\t" + xcert.GetPublicKeyString());
          }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(args[0] + ": Unable to readDER-encoded signature."); }
        }
    }
}
```